# Function to Calculate Height of Tree

Tags: c++, recursion

I am struggling to understand how the following `maxDepth` function, which calculates the height of a tree, actually works.

Consider the tree:

```
       1
      / \
     2   3
    / \
   4   5
        \
         8
```

In the code below, when we call the `maxDepth` function with the argument `root`, what is actually being calculated?

We declare two variables:

```
int lDepth = maxDepth(node->left);  
int rDepth = maxDepth(node->right);
```

so for `root` we are assigning:

```
int lDepth = maxDepth(2);  
int rDepth = maxDepth(3);
```

but there are no actual numeric values in here, so how do we call `if (lDepth > rDepth)` below this? There isn't anything to actually compare the values of is there? I would have thought the code in the `if` statement shouldn't execute.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

class node  
{  
    public: 
    int data;  
    node* left;  
    node* right;  
};  

int maxDepth(node* node)  
{  
    if (node == nullptr)  
        return 0;  
    else
    {  
        /* compute the depth of each subtree */
        int lDepth = maxDepth(node->left);  
        int rDepth = maxDepth(node->right);  

        /* use the larger one */
        if (lDepth > rDepth)  
            return(lDepth+1);

        else return(rDepth+1);  
    }  
}  

node* newNode(int data)  
{  
    node* Node = new node(); 
    Node->data = data;  
    Node->left = nullptr;  
    Node->right = nullptr;  

    return(Node);  
}  

int main()  
{  
    node *root = newNode(1);  

    root->left = newNode(2);  
    root->right = newNode(3);  
    root->left->left = newNode(4);  
    root->left->right = newNode(5);  
    root->left->right->right = newNode(8);  

    cout << "Height of tree is " << maxDepth(root);  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: `root->left` is not `2`, it is a pointer to the node containing `2` for its `data` member, so  `int lDepth = maxDepth(2);` is not a correct application.

Comment: Sure but we arent't comparing say node->left-> data with node->right->data. What are we actually comparing?

Comment: @Reno The height (or depth) of the left and right nodes are compared.

Comment: @uneven_mark but how? There isn't a height member variable and there is no counter variable keeping track of the number of calls to the recursive function call.

Comment: The height of the tree does not depend on the stored values, only on its structure.

Comment: @Reno `maxDepth` is recursively calling through the child nodes until it is called for a non-existent child (i.e. `node == nullptr`) in which case it returns `0`. Returning up the stack, it then always takes the larger of the two returned values for the subtrees and adds `1` which gives the height (equivalent depth) of the current subtree. If you have trouble with the concept of recursive functions, you might want to look this up in a textbook with some simpler examples.

Comment: @uneven_mark I understand the concept, factorial, fibonnacci etc. Defining lDepth as  "int lDepth = maxDepth(node->left)+1"; makes more sense as the +1 is essentially a counter. Without it, it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Reno You can add the `+1` already at that point if you want. The code in your question simply adds the `+1` later in the `return` statements. It doesn't make a difference to the comparison.

Comment: You can write `else return 1+std::max(maxDepth(node->left),maxDepth(node->right));`. Or, even, `return (node==nullptr) ? 0 : 1+std::max(maxDepth(node->left),maxDepth(node->right));`

Answer (score 0):

> We declare two variables:
>
> ```
> int lDepth = maxDepth(node->left);  
> int rDepth = maxDepth(node->right);
> ```
>
> so for root we are assigning:
>
> ```
> int lDepth = maxDepth(2);  
> int rDepth = maxDepth(3);
> ```

No. We are instead finding the depths of two trees

```
  2
 / \
4   5
     \
      8
```

and

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

The `maxDepth()` is a recursive function. So at the second level (one level lower to the root), there are two nodes `2` and `3`.

Look at `node 3` first, `maxDepth(3)` will allocate and call itself, then check whether there's a pointer or not, sincere there's not, it will return 0 from

```
if (node == nullptr)  
        return 0;
```

So `rDepth` is 0 for the `node` is 3.

Similarly, for the `node 2`, it will do the same, with multiple self-callings and assign an integer to the `lDepth`.

Thinking `maxDepth()` as an object instead of function might help.